# How can the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution be reconciled with the Boltzmann distribution?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, kinetic-theory

The Boltzmann distribution asserts that a state at a lower energy is more likely to be populated than a state at a higher energy level. However, the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution asserts that small velocities are the **least** likely to be observed. Since velocity is monotonically related to kinetic energy, how can the Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution be reconciled with the Boltzmann distribution?

Comment: You have to take into account not only the probability of getting a certain energy but also the *number of states at that energy*.

Comment: See [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/689193/247642)

Answer (score 0):

When you compute the Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution, you start with just the probability of getting a particular state, which in this case is parameterized by the momentum $\vec{p}$ so that
$$
P(\vec{v}) \propto e^{-\beta E_\vec{p}}
=e^{-\beta p^2/2m}
=e^{-\beta mv^2/2}\,.
$$
This distribution *does* show the characteristic decrease of the probability with the energy.  However, this should really be thought of as function of the components of the velocity vector, i.e.,
$$
P(v_x,v_y,v_z) = \frac{1}{Z} 
e^{-\beta m(v_x^2+v_y^2+v_z^2)/2}\,,
$$
where $Z$ is the partition function.

Now, this is *not* a function of speed directly.  In order to find the probability of getting a particular *speed*, you have to integrate over all possible *directions* of the velocity.  We can think of the velocity vectors as points in a "velocity"-space, and the states at a particular speed $v$ live on the surface of a sphere of radius $v$.  Thus as $v$ gets larger, the *number of states* increases.  At small $v$, this cases the probability of getting a particular $v$ to *rise*.  At large $v$, the exponential decay in the Boltzmann distribution takes over, and the probability getting a certain $v$ decreases.

Mathematically, if you want to compute the probability of getting a particular *speed* $v$, we consider the normalization condition,
\begin{align}
1 &= \int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}d\theta\int_0^{\infty}v^2dv\,P(\vec{v})\\
&= \int_0^{\infty}dv\,v^2\frac{1}{Z} 
\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi\int_0^{\pi}d\theta
e^{-\beta mv^2/2}\\
&=\int_0^{\infty}dv\,\frac{4\pi}{Z}v^2e^{-\beta mv^2/2}\,.
\end{align}
We can then identify the M-B distribution as
$$
P(v) = \frac{4\pi}{Z}v^2e^{-\beta mv^2/2}\,,
$$
and we can see how the factor of $v^2$$-$which comes mathematically from the integration measure in spherical coordinates and physically from the fact there are "more" states with larger speeds$-$causes the distribution to go to zero as $v\to0$.